# trigger a SAM defined lambda function via Localstack Sqs message event

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, localstack

**Context**:

currently I have two Lambda functions defined via local-stack, one is the SQS message publisher and the other is the SQS message consumer. Evidently I want the consumer to be invoked after the producer. In order to achieve this locally, localstack is used to simulate SQS queue.

this is my (partial) sam template:

```yaml
Metadata:
 AWS::CloudFormation::Interface:
  ParameterGroups:
   - Label: {default: 'Optional parameters'}
     Parameters:
      - ORDER_QUEUE_NAME

Parameters:
 ORDER_QUEUE_NAME:
  Type: String
  Description: 'order-queue'
  Default: 'order-queue'

Resources:
  MyQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: !Ref ORDER_QUEUE_NAME

  # MS Orders Async Publisher
  OrderPublisherFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./build/orders
      Handler: order-publisher-service.handler
      Role: !GetAtt RolesApp.Outputs.ReadTechnicalParamsRoleArn
      Environment:
        Variables:
          QUEUE_NAME: !Ref ORDER_QUEUE_NAME
      Events:
        createOrder:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref ApiGateway
            Path: /orders/_async
            Method: POST
      Policies:
        - Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Resource: '*'
            Action:
              - events:PutEvents
        - SQSPollerPolicy:
            QueueName: !Ref ORDER_QUEUE_NAME
        - SQSSendMessagePolicy:
            QueueName: !Ref ORDER_QUEUE_NAME

  # MS Orders Async Consumer
  OrderConsumerFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./build/orders
      Handler: order-consumer-service.handler
      Role: !GetAtt RolesApp.Outputs.ReadTechnicalParamsRoleArn
      Environment:
        Variables:
          QUEUE_NAME: !Ref ORDER_QUEUE_NAME
      Events:
        SqsEvent:
          Type: SQS
          Properties:
            Queue: !GetAtt MyQueue.Arn
            BatchSize: 10
      Policies:
        - SQSReceiveMessagePolicy:
            QueueName: !Ref ORDER_QUEUE_NAME
```

in localstack i created a queue with the following url:`http://localhost:4566/000000000000/order-queue`

**Problem**:

when i create a message in my producer and i sent it to the queue, i can see that it gets put in the queue as intented, i do however have to change localhost for `host.docker.internal` for localstack to receive the message. The consumer how ever does not get triggered after this message is registered in the queue.

One problem is probably that my SAM defined queue does not reference to the localstack queue and thus the consumer is not listening to the right queue.

Does anyone have experience in how to make this work?